# Specifiying part of the file name as a variable

Tags: excel, powerquery

good day all and thanks in advance for your help.
begginer here, i am tryin g to insert a variable as part of a file name of a query i did in excel but i can't seem to find the correct syntax for it. appreciate your help.

```
= let
    WeekNum = Number.ToText(Date.WeekOfYear(Date.From(DateTimeZone.From(DateTime.LocalNow())))-1),
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Vendor Performance Alarm-Monitoring_Week ***[WeekNum]***_2019.xlsx"), null, true),
```

Comment: its an excel query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file path is a string, so you can use concatenation.

```
...Vendor Performance Alarm-Monitoring_Week" & WeekNum & "_2019.xlsx...
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now i understand

Answer (score 0):

Just replace step Source:

```
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Vendor Performance Alarm-Monitoring_Week"
 & WeekNum & "_2019.xlsx"), null, true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I get it now.